# How does obedience correlate with the Big 5 factors of personality?

Tags: personality, big-five, obedience

I am looking for correlations for any Big 5 traits with obedience.
Are there any research reports on this, **available for me to read**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bègue et al. (2015)](http://archivesic.ccsd.cnrs.fr/sic_01158395/document) have recently investigated how the Big 5 traits predict obedience in a variant of the [Milgram paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment).

Participants believed they were participants in the pilot screening of a TV show. The talk show host (as the authority figure of the experiment) asked them to deliver electric shocks of increasing intensity to another participant (presumably a quiz contestant) whenever he or she gave an incorrect answer. As the intensity of the shocks increased, the contestant (in reality a confederate of the study) could be heard screaming and protesting, asking to stop the shocks. Nevertheless, the host insisted that the shocks should continue for the sake of the game show. The central measure of obedience was the highest intensity of the shock (when the participant refused to continue).

Result: **Conscientiousness and Agreeableness predicted obedience as expressed in the willingness to administer electric shocks of higher intensity as demanded by the authority figure**.

Here are the detailed results:

[image: Correlation table Bègue et al., 2015]

**References**

Bègue, L., Beauvois, J.-L., Courbet, D., Oberlé, D., Lepage, J., & Duke, A. A. (2015). Personality predicts obedience in a milgram paradigm. Journal of Personality, 83, 299–306. doi:10.1111/jopy.12104 ([pdf](http://archivesic.ccsd.cnrs.fr/sic_01158395/document))